# If $A$ and $B$ are $2\times 2$ matrices such that $A^2 - B^2$ is invertible, is $A-B$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples, inverse

Let $A$ and $B$ be $2\times 2$ matrices such that $A^2 - B^2$ is invertible. Is $A-B$ necessarily invertible?

This doesn't seem like it should be difficult but I just can't come up with a solution.

Comment: It is if $A$ and $B$ commute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I suspected the answer was no but couldn't find a counter example.